# Hide children of Wrap widget that overflow parent box of fixed size

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I am displaying a list of tags in an overlay at the bottom of a list screen. The length and number of the tags may vary, so I am using `Wrap` for a multi-line layout. Also, the overlay needs a maximum height, otherwise it could grow the size of the entire screen.

I tried to restrict the size with `SizedBox` and `ClipRect`, but that solution has two problems:

1. The chips could be cut in the middle, which looks unpleasant.
2. I don't have any clue how many chips are overflowing, so I cannot indicate to the user if the displayed list is incomplete.

**Question:**

Is there any way to hide all widgets completely that overflow the `ClipRect`? Like an alternative setting to Clip.hardEdge, or something that makes `Wrap` stop adding lines if there is no space?

And is there a way to tell that a widget is overflowing without manually calculating the dimensions of everything?

**Code:**

```
void _showFilterDisplayOverlay(Set<Tag> filterTags) {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _filterDisplayOverlay = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
          child: Material(
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  child: ClipRect(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                      child: Wrap(spacing: 8.0, runSpacing: 2.0, children: _buildFilterDisplayChips(filterTags))))));
    });
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(_filterDisplayOverlay!);
  });
}

List<Widget> _buildFilterDisplayChips(Set<Tag> filterTags) {
  return filterTags
      .map((tag) => InputChip(
            label: Text(tag.name),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          ))
      .toList();
}
```

I found the package [overflow_view](https://pub.dev/packages/overflow_view) on pub.dev, which would solve the problem of needing to know the number of overflowing widgets, but it currently does not support showing the elements in multiple lines like `Wrap` does (feature has been requested on GitHub a while ago).

Comment: check `Flow` widget and use the custom delegate class to find out what widgets to show and what not

Comment: @pskink You mean I should replace the `Wrap` with an implementation of `Flow` that simulates the way `Wrap` arranges the chips? I gave it a try, but somehow the `InputChip` widgets that I pass to `Flow` as children are always the size of the entire parent `SizedBox`. I assumed that the size of the chips would only depend on the label and `labelStyle` and I could check that size to determine the positioning. It seems that without `Wrap`, the size of chips only depends on the constraints of its parent. Any ideas?

Comment: override this method https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9cd3d0d9ff/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/flow.dart#L90, by default, afair it's fixed parent size - you can verify it by simple `print(constraints)` - I think that returning `constraints.loosen()` will be enough

Comment: Thanks a lot! I returned constraints with a minimum width/height of 0 and a maximum of `double.infinity` and now the chips are the correct size! Awesome! I may actually consider releasing this component as a package.

Comment: no no no, don't use infinity, `constraints.loosen()` does not work?

Comment: Ah yeah, that's even better.

Comment: btw last month I wrote a very thin wrapper using `Flow` widget so that you can use it as a normal `Stack` widget and you can get the child and parent size for a precise positioning: https://gist.github.com/pskink/10c8fd372113f0b36570db96d58d818e#file-flow_stack-dart-L21 (there is a small demo attached in the same file)

Comment: update: seems that you don't need  `getConstraintsForChild` - instead override `getSize` and remove outer `SizedBox` - I'm not 100% sure but it should work

Comment: Yest, it works.

Comment: this is why you had "as children are always the size of the entire parent SizedBox" - that `SizedBox` forced the size of not only the `Flow` widget but also its children - the `BoxConstraints` were "tight"

Comment: btw you could post a self answer here showing your code for someone who has the similar problem

Comment: Yeah, will do, but the algorithm got quite complex, so I will probably upload it to GitHub and link it.

Comment: My solution also implements padding and spacing, skips elements that are wider than the container width and adds a "..." chip at the end if any chips had to be left out.

Comment: ah, ok, seems like fully fledged widget ... :-)

Comment: i wonder if your '... chip' contains any information about a number of chips that were not shown? or it shows just 3 dots? I had the same problem where I had to modify one widget passed in `children: ....` parameter (I am assuming your ellipsis widget is passed as a last widget in `children` param) but I was not able to find a really good solution

Comment: Yeah, it just shows three dots for now. I am keeping track of the exact number of hidden chips, but if I displayed that number, the width of that chip would be dynamic again, which makes the whole thing more complicated...